# $lookup in mongoose returns empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schema namely Username and UserOrganization schema which is of follows:

```
const UsernameSchema = new Schema ({
username: {type: String, unique: true},
displayUsername: {type: String},
type: {type: String},
refId: {type: String},
current: {type: Boolean},
forward: {type: Date}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Username', UsernameSchema);

const UserOrganizationSchema = new Schema({
userId: {type: String},
orgId: {type: String},
roles: [{type: String}],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserOrganization', UserOrganizationSchema);
```

here orgId of UserOrganization schema is equal to refId of Username schema.
Now when i try the following code:

```
Username.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'UserOrganization.collection.name',
      localField: 'refId',
      foreignField: 'orgId',
      as: 'test',
    },
  }])
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
)}
```

console.log(data) returns

```
[{ _id: 5c64f9914c22010ee00fb47f,
 username: 'sub',
 displayUsername: 'sub_syd',
 refId: '5c64f9914c22010ee00fb47c',
 type: 'org',
 current: false,
 __v: 0,
 test: [] }]
```

where test field is empty. Is there any problem with my code?
Thanks In Advance.

PS: Solutions from previous similar StackOverflow question did not work for me.

**Edit**

**UserOrganization** Collection

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c663050dfc59c2428a6662a"),
"roles" : [
    "member"
],
"userId" : "5c62600a63c3c52e3135d20b",
"orgId" : "5c628478ca7cc030c86a1a6c",
"__v" : 0
}
```

**Username** Collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c628478ca7cc030c86a1a6e"),
"username" : "test1",
"displayUsername" : "test_1",
"refId" : "5c628478ca7cc030c86a1a6c",
"type" : "organization",
"current" : false,
"__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: It should be without quotes `from: UserOrganization.collection.name` or `from: "userorganisations"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: $lookup returns empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266339/mongodb-lookup-returns-empty-array)

Comment: no @AnthonyWinzlet, it's not duplicate, I tried the solution from that question and it did not solve for me.

Comment: Ok then show some sample documents from both the collections

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I have updated it with sample document from two collection.

Comment: See it working https://mongoplayground.net/p/s7jpl64ArmZ

Comment: What was the mistake, I couldn't find any difference from my code

Comment: Have your tired with my first comment?

Comment: Yes, it returns "test: [ [Object], [Object] ] }," any way to show the data?

Comment: Yes that is the data. In console you can see like that. If you want remove cover then use .dot notation. Something like `test[0]`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Now you can mark it as duplicate