# MongoDB aggregate lookup, no records

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When doing `.aggregate` on users collection, with `$lookup`, an `oauth` field is empty

I've already tried to use `pipeline` and `local/foreign` fields

```
User.aggregate([
        {
          $match: objectQuery,
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'OAuthAccessToken',
            as: 'oauth',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'user'
          }
      ])
```

There is no any error message, `oauth` field is empty.

`_id` in `User` collection is type `string`

`user` in `OAuthAccessToken` collection is type `string`

Comment: Could you show the data you're running this query on (some sample documents) ?

Comment: I'm using `mongoose` in version `4.13.18`, `mongodb` version is `4.0.4`

`queryObject`
```
{ type: 'USER' }
```

I do not think it matters, records are pulled correctly without lookup

`User` sample:

```
_id: '7662a246-9370-47d8-9f31-5dd83a9b9521',
username: 'test'
```

`OAuthAccessTokens`:
```
_id: ObjectId("5cdaacc0fb72073f86e25fc5"),
user: '7662a246-9370-47d8-9f31-5dd83a9b9521'
```

Comment: Can you change from `OAuthAccessToken` to `OAuthAccessTokens` in **from** expression.

Comment: Yeah, I've discovered that.
Tried with `OAuthAccessTokens`, replaced it to `oauthaccesstokens` and it works right now. Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: $lookup returns empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266339/mongodb-lookup-returns-empty-array)

Comment: MongoDB does lower case, when you create collection, but in lookup - it's not happening

Comment: No mongodb does not do anything. It is all about `mongoose`. You can have a look at the answers for more info.